# Dog howls while I take out other dog

Tags: dogs

My father passed away in January and I inherited his 8-year-old lab/boxer. In the past when my father was in the hospital, Buddy would come and stay with me and my 8-year-old dog Trax (Yorkie/Schnauzer mix). Buddy never howled before when I would take Trax out to do his business but now I am hearing Buddy howling in my apartment from downstairs outside. Buddy gets taken out first and has food and water available while I take Trax out.

Also because Buddy is 105 lbs I can't take both dogs out at the same time to go potty.

What can I do to get him to stop?

Comment: Considering he lost his owner, I wonder if its separation anxiety of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Practice taking them out together, even if it's not ideal. Start by walking them together up and down the hall, or to the mailbox, or around the building once. They will adapt and you will all bond as a family unit. End result is that Buddy will learn that he is part of your family now and not "all alone". Baby steps can make everyone more comfortable with this arrangement.

Comment: Where comes your experience from? Did you had the same problem and this solution worked well? Or did you found a website or book of experienced people?

Comment: 40 years of dogs. Dogs of all types and ages. Adopted as adults, puppies. Purebreds, mutts. etc. Lots of dogs over lots of years. So, my experience is directly related to "life".

Comment: Would you please include this in your answer? It will help people to get a feeling about your knowledge. Because this is not a common forum and we handle here living beings, this is important :)

Comment: @elbrant tbf - if you're someone who's got experience fostering dogs in similar situations, mentioning that does have some value IMO

Answer (score -1):

I am very sorry for your loss.

As Journeyman Geek has said, it could be separation anxiety considering his owner just passed on. One possibility is that the other dog, (Trax) may be in some way linked up with his memory of your father, because he was in close contact with both of them on a regular basis. That's only a theory though, and I could be wrong. The most likely explanation is just separation anxiety. This howling may continue until your dog just realizes that his owner will never be coming back.

EDIT: there is really no way to know for sure why it is happening. You can try taking them out together, but make sure that they don't hurt each other, consider one is much bigger than the other.

Comment: This does not provide a real solution to the question. Just guessing. This is not welcome here...

Comment: @Allerleirauh no it's not that this is not welcome here, it's that OP asked a bad question. There is absolutely no way to know for sure. It's really not my fault. I will edit to include this.

Comment: Then help the OP to improve the question by making comments or edit it!

Comment: Well - there's a reason I posted it as a comment. *That* its separation anxiety is plausible. What to do is more important. And my aunt's dog lost *2* owners and... I believe he never quite got she was never coming back. Not everything heals up right, but there's ways and such to make things better.